# Expo xde not using style

Tags: react-native, scrollview

When I run following code in the sandbox https://snackexpo.io it works fine. But when I run from the Expo xde I get Invariant Violation: Scrollview child layout must be applied through the contentContainerStyle prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet,   ScrollView } from 'react-native';



export default class App extends React.Component {
  blockJS(){
  const done = Date.now() + 5000
  console.log('blocking')
  while(Date.now() < done){done}
  console.log('not blocking')

  }
  render() {
    return (

      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Button title='Block js' onPress={()=> this.blockJS()}/>
      </ScrollView>

    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollView does not support `alignItems` and `justifyContent` unless it is passed as a [`contentContainerStyle`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentcontainerstyle) or **wrap** your contents inside and pass the `styles` to them.

You can change it as follows

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
        <Button title='Block js' onPress={()=> this.blockJS()}/>
      </ScrollView>
```

**Or as a wrapper**

```
// flex will only be applied on contentContainer to get it inherited
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Text>Some sample text</Text>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks, I understand your example and how to fix but what do you mean by ...unless it is passed as a contentContainerStyle or wrap your contents inside and pass the styles   ? any ideas of why you don't have to do this in the sandbox?

Comment: You can wrap your child components in a single `view` and pass same styles for `alignment` to it

Comment: sorta of works but doesn't provide the layout as applying the style to the ScrollView

Comment: Updated the answer